# Ping 100% packet loss under Openwrt,driver relevant issue

Tags: ethernet, openwrt

Is there anyone who's familiar with Atheros solution and OpenWrt system ?
My testbed runs well under Atheros-SDK image while it was found that my ethernet interface(eth0) arose "ping 100% packet loss" when running on OpenWrt image. I even continue to use the registers' setting value,e.g.,ETH_CONF,XMII_CONF,but it doesn't work yet.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.Thanks!!
    my ethernet setting at arch/mips/ath79/mach-db120.c is:

```
ath79_register_mdio(0, ~(BIT(5)));
ath79_eth0_data.phy_if_mode = PHY_INTERFACE_MODE_RGMII;
ath79_eth0_data.phy_mask = BIT(5);default is BIT(0)
ath79_eth0_data.mii_bus_dev = &ath79_mdio0_device.dev;
ath79_eth0_pll_data.pll_1000 = 0x06000000;
ath79_eth0_data.duplex = DUPLEX_FULL;
ath79_register_eth(0);
```

If I modified the th79_eth0_pll_data.pll_1000 to 0x46000000

(set the 1805002c GIGE_QUAD bit),then it can ping but still has 3%-5% or even more ping loss.strange! I realy want to know is there any issue with ag71xx relevant code ?
sectional bootlog is:

```
Starting kernel ...
......
......
[ 0.650000] libphy: ag71xx_mdio: probed
[ 0.650000] eth0: Atheros AG71xx at 0xb9000000, irq 4, mode:RGMII
[ 1.470000] ag71xx ag71xx.0 eth0: connected to PHY at ag71xx-mdio.0:05 [uid=004dd072, driver=Generic PHY]
root@OpenWrt:/# ping 192.168.1.99
PING 192.168.1.99 (192.168.1.99): 56 data bytes
C
--- 192.168.1.99 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
root@OpenWrt:/#
```

Comment: I am using the OpenWrt trunk, barrier breaker.My board is Atheros DB120..kernel version is 3.7.4 or above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which OpenWRT version you are using  to get some answer !

Comment: I am using the OpenWrt trunk, barrier breaker.My board is Atheros DB120..kernel version is 3.7.4 or above.